# Release Management OnPremise with VSO

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management, azure-devops

Is it possible to connect Release Management OnPremise with Visual Studio Online that has an OnPremise BuildServer?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because on-premise Release Management Server 2013/2015 can't talk to VSTS at all.

You'll be better off using the Release hub in VSTS, since that's a native, fully integrated release management solution.